# Как исправить ошибку (Caused by: org.gradle.internal...)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method Android() for arguments [build_5ym1t38qo4yxk7wcvezwkn9gd$_run_closure1@5c69a9fd] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 27
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "info.androidhive.bottomnavigation"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 29
    multiDexEnabled true


}

dexOptions {
    // Prevent OutOfMemory with MultiDex during the build phase
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }


}
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = []// <-- disable automatic ndk-build call
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // RecyclerView
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    // CardView
    implementation 'com.android.support:bottomnavigation-v7:23.0.0'

    // volley http library
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    // glide image library
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
}
```

Comment: Что-то синтаксиса JavaScript не заметил, укажите, пожалуйста, это место.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка здесь:

```
Android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 27
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

Должно быть с маленькой буквы `android`